# Append images to a video

Tags: c#, opencv, video, avi

Due to the lack of DirectShow filter for the Kinect, I am forced to capture each RGB bitmap individually and merge them.

I am currently using the fragile AviFile [C# Wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library), which causes slow frame rate and syncing issues with the audio.

How would you suggest to capture and append a bitmap to a video in real-time ?

Comment: Can you give a little more information on the implementation's specifics?

Comment: You can capture frame by frame and then feed them into DirectShow pipeline for further processing. After all, you inevitably need video compressor, which would be either DShow, or FFmpeg - not so many great options out there. Whatever your preference is, DirectShow can get you real time video compression and file writing, with audio and with sync.

Comment: quick and dirty: just save them as a series of numbered jpges - then you can make them into a video using after effects or something like that.